# Building objects with jq

Tags: json, object, jq

Using `jq` I'd like to convert data of the format:

```
{
  "key": "something-else",
  "value": {
    "value": "bloop",
    "isEncrypted": false
  }
}
{
  "key": "something",
  "value": {
    "value": "blah",
    "isEncrypted": false
  }
}
```

To the format:

```
{
  something: "blah",
  something-else: "bloop"
}
```

Filtering out 'encrypted values' along the way. How can I achieve this? I've gotten as far as the following:

```
.parameters | to_entries[] | select (.value.isEncrypted == false) | .key + ": " + .value.value
```

Which produces:

```
"something-else: bloop"
"something: blah"
```

Close, but not there just yet. I suspect that there's some clever function for this.

Answer (score 2):

Given the example input, here's a simple solution, assuming the stream of objects is available as an array. (This can be done using `jq -s` if the JSON objects are given as input to jq, or in your case, following your example, simply using `.parameters | to_entries`).

```
map( select(.value.isEncrypted == false) | {(.key): .value.value } )
| add
```

This produces the JSON object:

```
{
  "something-else": "bloop",
  "something": "blah"
}
```

The key ideas here are:

- the syntax for object construction: `{( KEYNAME ): VALUE}`
- `add`

One way to gain an understanding of how this works is to run the first part of the filter (map(...)) first.

#### Using `keys_unsorted`

If you want to avoid the overhead of `to_entries`, you might want to consider the following approach, which piggy-backs off your implicit description of `.parameters`:

```
.parameters
| [ keys_unsorted[] as $k
  | if .[$k].isEncrypted == false 
    then { ($k) : .[$k].value } else empty end ]
| add
```